# Alerting and monitoring for azure webjob

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I am looking for a way to monitor and alert when a webjob fails. Is there any tools(Apart from cloudmonix and Newrelic) that can support this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the **WebJobs SDK**, you might take a look at the new `ErrorTrigger` binding that was recently added ([details here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions)). It allows you to define a job function that will automatically be triggered when errors reach a certain threshold. Here's an example function that will be called whenever 10 errors occur within a 30 minute sliding window (throttled at a maximum of 1 notification per hour):

```
 public static void ErrorMonitor(
    [ErrorTrigger("0:30:00", 10, Throttle = "1:00:00")] TraceFilter filter, 
    TextWriter log)
 {
      // Access error details and send an email/SMS, etc.

      // log last 5 detailed errors to the Dashboard
      log.WriteLine(filter.GetDetailedMessage(5));
 }
```

See the [Error Monitoring wiki page](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/Error-Monitoring) for more information.